# Where is PHP getting 1028M memory limit?

Tags: php

When running phpinfo on my server I see there is a limit of 1028M, and one of my scripts requires a one-time use of a LOT of memory.

Is there any way I can remove this limit, and let swap handle the memory usage?

The string "1028" does not appear in any php file on my server. In /etc/php.ini the limit is set to -1.

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec grep -il 1028 {} \;
```

Comment: Curiosity killed the cat, what do you do that eat all that RAM :-)

Answer (score 2):

In 32 bit operating systems, PHP can only use up to 1.5Gb of ram. (At least that is what I have discovered in practice). If you want to allow more memory for PHP, you will need to switch to 64 bit operating systems.

The memory limit in the php.ini file, when set to -1 means to use all available memory. But it is misleading.

My best guess is that you are running it under windows or linux 32 bit...

Comment: It was an issue with a config file somewhere; my VPS provider changed it for me

Answer (score 0):

the memory limit can be set as `memory_limit` in your `php.ini` - thats the reason you couldn't find it, you're just searching for `*.php` files and not `*.ini`.

for more information, take a look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). note that you might also have to increase the `max_execution_time` for such a big script.

Comment: In /etc/php.ini it is set to -1.

Answer (score 0):

It's in your .ini file or set in your code somewhere. Since your search in .php files did not give any result it's most likely in your ini file.

Answer (score 0):

why remove anything? use ini_set() and set whatever amount you wish for the script that requires it.

BTW, 1028M is A LOT of memory.

Comment: I think the max memory cannot be set by the ini_set.

Comment: ugh, and what it says? can't you be a little more certain please?

Comment: Well it says "Not all the available options can be changed using ini_set()."

Comment: so, it says that memory_limit is among them?

Comment: It just says not all options are available... Anyway, it also makes bad programming sense to change setting options in the program itself. It is better to centralise the settings in the setting.ini file so that in future, when another setting issue occurs, you can be 100% sure that the settings is only set in 1 location, instead of having to hunt around in the source codes to see if it has been changed in other locations.

Comment: really? So, you thinks that raising memory limit for the whole application is better than setting it for the only script requires it?

Comment: yes. Otherwise if the settings are placed all over the codes, and there is any error with the setting, it is difficult to know which part of the codes caused it. This way, it makes it easier for "non-experienced" programmers to debug and maintain the codes. You cannot expect every programmer to be experts like you and me... wink* wink*...

Comment: Programming is not just abot writing the most efficient codes available. SOmetimes it needs to take into consideration the maintainability of the applications, as well as the ease of use.

Comment: So Col. Shrapnel@ why do you think it is a good idea to put change the settings in the codes instead?